# 503 Service Unavailable apache 2.4.27 php-fpm intermittently

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

Recently installed a new server with Apache 2.4.27  php 7.0 with php-fpm.  I have a phpboard application that is functional, however occasionally I'm receiving a 503 on the index.php

In the vhost file I have it setup as follows:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
       SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9002"
</FilesMatch>
```

I also enabled trace logging on Apache.  The comparison between the one session that works and doesn't work is almost identical, except one time it receives a 503 the other time it doesn't.

Attached is the results from the diff checker: https://www.diffchecker.com/6sMLIx38

The file on the left works / The file on the right has the 503.

Any thoughts??  This

Comment: diff checker expired. maybe you can show some of the diff in your question?